# Vertx thread blocked warnings

Tags: vert.x

I am running a vert.x application on ubuntu server. It has an HTTPServer running on port 3000. Application is working fine but sometimes I am seeing following warnings:

```
Dec 08, 2017 1:23:43 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 138013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:44 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 139014 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:45 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 140013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:46 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 141013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:47 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 142013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:48 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 143013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:49 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 144013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 08, 2017 1:23:50 AM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 145013 ms, time limit is 60000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:441)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$500(NativePRNG.java:331)
    at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineGenerateSeed(NativePRNG.java:226)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:533)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG.lambda$null$0(PRNG.java:78)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.PRNG$$Lambda$204/767088095.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:271)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$206/1202956360.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am not able to understand what is causing these warnings to appear. At the time of warnings, the server was idle with 0 traffic on the application. Also, I am running a scheduler using vertx periodic, which makes query to mongo every 15 secs.

```
vertx.setPeriodic(15000, r -> someService.check()); // Every 15 seconds
```

Comment: Please show the code in the .check(). It is possible for something in it to be blocking. For example in my case I was doing large json serialization which caused the Warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is not enough entropy (server idle) to feed the PRNG. So instead of returning quickly the `SecureRandom.generateSeed` method blocks until it gets enough data.

Depending on your hardware, you may be able to speed up the process with [`rng-tools`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rng-tools).

Comment: Its a 1 GB droplet machine, is it the memory problem? Also running `periodic` mongo queries with interval of 15 secs, is it fine?

Comment: Yes, the periodic queries are fine. No it's not a memory problem. If you're on a cloud machine, then you can't do much. Just ignore the warning (it's harmless).

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing blocking api calls using vertx.executeBlocking() ? It appears to me you might have a blocking API call somewhere in your someService.check() or anywhere else

Comment: No, there is no blocking API calls. `service.check()` is only making queries to mongo DB using vertx-mongo-client.

Comment: Generally, calls to DB uses @Transactional, which is blocking by default.