# In vert.x java app, how to display line numbers in stacktrace , instead of "Unknown Source"?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have an application based on Vert.x.

When it throws exceptions there are no line numbers, for example:

```
at com.someapp.class1.a(Unknown Source)
at com.someapp.class1.a(Unknown Source)
at com.someapp.class2.a(Unknown Source)
at com.someapp.class2.a(Unknown Source)
at com.someapp.class3.a(Unknown Source)
at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$compose$0(Future.java:227)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:125)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:86)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:151)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:18)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:79)
at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$compose$1(Future.java:270)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:125)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:86)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:151)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:18)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:125)
at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:86)
```

How do I configure it to show line numbers instead of "`Unknown Source`"?

Comment: Is this the full stack trace?

Comment: Nope. But rest of the stack has line numbers

Comment: Having the entire log  trace would be much better for investigation

Comment: I have put the full trace

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this occurs when there is some blocking on the even-loop thread. Remember the Vert.x golden rule is :

> Do not Block the Event Loop

You may want to check the code that runs in your class.

[This](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/2798) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708516/vertx-thread-blocked-warnings) may be of help

Comment: How "blocking the event loop" is related to my question of how to format displaying stacktrace? I did not ask how to prevent the error, but how to display its stacktrace correctly